# What is R algorithm for dummy coding model matrix?

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I noticed when using a dummy coding for fitting my linear models R excludes certain parameters when forming model matrix. What is the R algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Maybe start by reading about the `contrasts` argument to `?lm`, which will lead to `?model.matrix` and also the documentation at `?contr.treatment`. Maybe a book on linear model theory might be in order, too, since the documentation will presume that you have a basic understanding of the math.

Comment: @joran I believe I do understand contrast and coding. Dummy coding is merely a way of grouping coefficients in a regression equation, but it is not clear how R makes the choice of grouping, since after all, the choice of grouping is not unique. For simple cases, I do understand the default contrasts but for complex cases my understanding seems to fall apart

Comment: Then I suspect the documentation I referred to ought to be sufficient. The defaults are shown in `options("contrasts")`.

Answer (score 2):

It is *not* well documented, but it goes back to whatever pivoting algorithm the underlying LAPACK code uses:

from the [source code of lm.fit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/7ada5f74f96dd8214e4bf0c43fda5757d348e74e/src/library/stats/R/lm.R#L114):

```
z <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y, tol, FALSE)
...
coef <- z$coefficients
pivot <- z$pivot
...
r2 <- if(z$rank < p) (z$rank+1L):p else integer()
if (is.matrix(y)) {
    ....
} else {
    coef[r2] <- NA
    ## avoid copy
    if(z$pivoted) coef[pivot] <- coef
    ...
}
```

If you want to dig back further, you need to look into [dqrdc2.f](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/appl/dqrdc2.f), which says (for what it's worth):

> c     dqrdc2 uses householder transformations to compute the qr 
>   c factorization of an n by p matrix x.  a limited column 
>   c     pivoting strategy based on the 2-norms of the reduced columns 
>   c     moves columns with near-zero norm to the right-hand edge of 
>   c     the x matrix.  this strategy means that sequential one 
>   c     degree-of-freedom effects can be computed in a natural way.

*In practice* I have generally found that R eliminates the last (rightmost) column of a set of collinear predictor variables ...

Comment: Thanks. I think you are talking about linearly dependent columns when performing QR factorization. I am talking about the stage of forming the model matrix. These two stages solve the problem of linear dependence, but I believe are slightly different. You are talking about how linearly dependent columns, which are already in the model matrix, being moved out of the rank of the matrix by pivoting. I am asking how does R decide which parameters are excluded, when forming the model matrix. NOT AFTER